# SSIS - Retrieve variable value from controle flow (no using script task) to data flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, msbi

I'm facing an issue with a case where I need to retrieve variable value from controle fow to data flow.

The value of the variable in controle flow = 3 but in data flow = 0 as if the value was not passed.

Any idea please ?

FYI, scope of the variable = package & the value of the variable is not from script task.

[image]
[image]

Thank you.